# Rewrite Custom WordPress Uploads Folder with .htaccess to wp-load.php with extra get parameters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, upload

> Or how to redirect url with query parameter from media image to php
> script

I have a custom folder in wp-uploads:
`wp-content/uploads/secure`

with htaccess as follow:
`wp-content/uploads/secure/.htaccess`

medias are organized in subfolders of `wp-content/uploads/secure`

like `wp-content/uploads/secure/{$user_id}/{$date}/` (This is an example)

I output images src as

```
\<img src="wp-content/uploads/secure/my-image.jpg?attachment_id=32985"\>
```

I would like the htaccess to redirect directory images to
`/wp-load.php/?get_secure_image=32985`

File: `wp-content/uploads/secure/.htaccess`

```
\# BEGIN block unauthentified uploads folder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp-load.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
\# END block unauthentified uploads folder
```

I don't know how to pass **get_secure_image** GET parameter to `wp-load.php` via htaccess or other params

My idea then is to have an action on init like this:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['get_secure_image'])){
        $attachment_id=absint($_GET['get_secure_image']);
        if(user_has_access($attachment_id)){
            $file=get_attached_file($attachment_id);
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
        exit('<img src="data:image/png;base64,FORBIDDEN_IMAGE_BASE64">');
    }
})
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry for my french english. Did my best
If you have a good doc / tutorial about advanced htaccess I am more than interested